# Writting down $subtract in No-SQL MongoDB in a sophisticated way

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-atlas

I'm doing MongoDB Academy, and for this question:

> What is the difference between the number of people born in 1998 and the number of people born after 1998 in the sample_training.trips collection?

The simplest way is to do this is (the way they expect you to answer):

```
db.trips.find({"birth year":1988}).count()
```

and:

```
db.trips.find({"birth year":{$gt:1988}}).count()
```

then, manually calculate.

I'm not familiar with programming and code syntax but, wondering about a sophisticated method, something like the code bellow can be improved.

```
db.trips.aggregate({$subtract:[db.trips.find({"pop":1988}).count(),db.trips.find({"pop":{$gt:1988}}).count()]})
```

Note: Atlas "free subscriber" don't allow to use $subtract in queries, so I even tested if it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the number of people born in the year 1998 and after 1988 using the following approach that too with just one aggregate query.

Aggregate pipeline stages:

1. Select only those records where the `birth year` is equal or greater than `1988`
2. Group the number of people by the `birth year`
3. Add a new field as `born_on` to every record using the `$cond` operator in the `$project` stage
4. Group record again by the newly added field `born_on`, which will now give you only two records with count as `on_1988` and `after_1988`

The query is as following

```
db.trips.aggregate([
{
  "$match":{
     "birth year":{
        "$gte":1988
     }
  }
},
{
  "$group":{
     "_id":"$birth year",
     "count":{
        "$sum":1
     }
  }
},
{
  "$project":{
     "count":"$count",
     "born_on":{
        "$cond":[
           {
              "$eq":[
                 "$_id",
                 1988
              ]
           },
           "on_1988",
           "after_1988"
        ]
     }
  }
},
{
  "$group":{
     "_id":"$born_on",
     "total":{
        "$sum":"$count"
     }
  }
}
])
```

** There could be another more optimized way of achieving the same result but this also works

Comment: next goal is: install a VM with suse to compare computing speed and eficiency in all ways of achieving this result. if u find any other way, fell free to share.

Answer (score 1):

Much Simpler way use:
(query 1) - (query 2)

```
 db.trips.find({"birth year":{"$gt":1998}}).count() - db.trips.find({"birth year":1998}).count()
```

You'll get the result as an integer

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following queries to get this value:

```
db.trips.find( { "birth year": { "$gt": 1998 } } ).count()
db.trips.find( { "birth year": 1998 } ).count()
```

Use the `$gt` instead of `$gte` operator to exclude all 1998 births, and then see how many people were born in 1998 by using implicit equality, then subtract the two values to get the difference.